# refine keyword filename search

Tags: python

I am currently trying to locate documents containing a certain keyword in the title. I have been successfully to some extent but not very robust. The keyword I am searching for is 'Monthly Reports'. Is there a way to search for this keyword without being case sensitive? There a currently a few documents that are being excluded because they are title 'Monthly reports' or 'monthly reports' and so on. This is what I have so far.

```
import os
import shutil

dest = '//server/to_user/folder'
path = '//server/from_user/'
keyword = 'Monthly Report'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
   for name in files:
      if keyword in name:
        #shutil.copy(path + name, dest)
         print name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert it to lowercase and compare it to a lowercase string.

Doing `name.lower()` will return an all lowercase string.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to search for this keyword without being case sensitive?

Sure, just make your keyword all one case, let's say lower case, then `if keyword in name.lower()` will be case-insensitive, since you coerced to a single case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use build-in string method lower() witch will return lower case string and then you can compare!

you can check this link for more build-in string methods.
[Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_strings.htm)